# Somatório total dos valores de todas as datas

Tags: mysql, sql

Como que eu faço para somar X valores de uma data especifica e comparar se o valor somado é maior que 100?

```
/*
Data das consultas, e para cada data o somatório total dos valores, desde que este total seja maior do que 100.00. 
*/

SELECT 
    c.data AS 'Data Consul.', SUM(c.valor) AS 'Total dia'
FROM
    consulta c
WHERE
    c.valor > 100
GROUP BY c.data;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o operador `HAVING`

```
SELECT 
    c.data AS 'DataConsul.', SUM(c.valor) AS TotalDia
FROM
    consulta c
GROUP BY 
    c.data
HAVING
    TotalDia > 100;
```

Estou sem ambiente MySQL para testar, qualquer erro me fale que eu edito aqui

Comment: valeu, brother funcionou certinho...

Comment: valeu, amigo feito :)